# SQL syntax letter size

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

Can someone explain what is the difference between the below two queries:

```
SELECT x.mid,  
       x.lenmsec, 
       (SELECT AVG(M.lenmsec) FROM movies_list M WHERE M.mid<>x.mid) 
FROM movies_list x
```

and

```
SELECT x.mid,  
       x.lenmsec, 
       (SELECT AVG(m.lenmsec) FROM movies_list m WHERE m.mid<>x.mid) 
FROM movies_list x
```

These queries are almost identical, there is only one difference is, the size of the letter 'M' in the subquery.

First query doesn't work properly, but second one works fine, but why?

Comment: How do you know that 1st doesn't work? Does it return message error?

Comment: post error occurring in first query

Comment: There is no difference. SQL is _not_ case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

Works perfect. What is the issue you are facing?

```
SQL> select * from movies_list;

       MID    LENMSEC
---------- ----------
         1          1
         1          1
         1          1
         1          2
         1          3

         SQL> SELECT x.mid,  x.lenmsec, (SELECT AVG(M.lenmsec) FROM movies_list M WHERE M.mid<>x.mid) FROM movies_list x ;


       MID    LENMSEC (SELECTAVG(M.LENMSEC)FROMMOVIES_LISTMWHEREM.MID<>X.MID)
---------- ---------- -------------------------------------------------------
         1          1
         1          1
         1          1
         1          2
         1          3

SQL> SELECT x.mid,  x.lenmsec, (SELECT AVG(m.lenmsec) FROM movies_list m WHERE m.mid<>x.mid) FROM movies_list x ;

       MID    LENMSEC (SELECTAVG(M.LENMSEC)FROMMOVIES_LISTMWHEREM.MID<>X.MID)
---------- ---------- -------------------------------------------------------
         1          1
         1          1
         1          1
         1          2
         1          3
```